# why mysql does not reclaim free space in ibd file?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, mysql5

I am using mysql5, and I want to shrink some 'deleted' spaces in `ibd` file. I already search for 'optimize table' option, but I cannot use it now, because it is a very critical table. It uses 19G in Mysql, but 33G in OS. I just figure out 33G is getting an increase.

I heard that it reuses in 33G spaces, like the black area. But why it increases every day?

MySQL does not reuse these free spaces? I mean, about 24G is never reused?

Thanks for the read, I hope not my poor English makes you are confused when you read it.

Comment: Which mysql version? Do you have innnodb_file_per_table set? By how much is it increasing daily (both space and rows)? Reuse should happen. Is 33G just the size of the ibd file for the critical table?

Comment: This isn't really a question for SO.  First off you should indicate in your question whether this is a per table setup or a shared tablespace.  If not using  Innodb_file_per_table you are out of luck.  The default is usually shared, so all the innodb tables will be in one IBD.  If you are using  Innodb_file_per_table then you have a chance to recover space.  You should also investigate pt-online-schema from Percona as a possible workaround for optimize write locking.

Comment: thanks for reply. I am sorry about I did not write down specific version and setup.
innnodb_file_per_table is ON. and pt-online-schema is good choise, but my boss cannot trust this tool..because this is not formal one.. :(

Comment: my version is Distrib 5.0.95

Comment: Percona toolkint is as formal as it gets in the open source world. You have far, far bigger problems in terms of still running MySQL 5.0, this has been deprecated and with no bug and security fixes in many years.

Comment: I appreciate your kindness , Thanks

Comment: is it helpful to 'drop table' and then remake same table?

Answer (score 0):

The option you are looking for is `innodb_use_trim=1`, in combination with `innodb_file_per_table=1`, if the version of MySQL you are using is new enough to have it. This will release back empty pages by punching holes in the tablespace files.

Comment: Forget the "trim":  Introduced: MariaDB 10.1.0, MariaDB 10.0.15 Fusion-io
Deprecated: MariaDB 10.2.4
Removed: MariaDB 10.3.0.  Anyway, it only applied to `COMPRESS`.

Comment: The OP said they were using MySQL 5. innodb_use_trim is always on in MariaDB 10.3+.

Answer (score 0):

The valid parts of a table are scattered throughout the `.ibd`. file.  The Operating System does not have a way to reuse freed up pieces from the middle of a table.

So, InnoDB never shrinks a tablespace, only grows it.

Meanwhile, new `INSERTs` will fill in some of the freed space.

What led to this situation?  Did you `DELETE` lots of rows?  If you expect to do another big `DELETE`, see the following advice for next time:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Meanwhile, *if* the table was created with `innodb_file_per_table = 1`, then `OPTIMIZE TABLE` will copy the table over and release the old copy to the OS.  But...  You need extra disk space to do the task.  And it will block some operations against the table.  (The details depend on which version of MySQL/MariaDB you are using.)

Why do you need to recoup the space?  If you are not running low on disk space, then does it really matter?

**Low on space?**

Show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There may be some tips on making the table smaller.  (This does not solve the problem, but delays future problems.)  For example, if an `INT` (4 bytes) can be changed to `SMALLINT` (2 bytes), that could help shrink the table.  Or an `INDEX` might be redundant; `DROPping` it would help.

The `ALTER` to change such things might do the `OPTIMIZE` at the same time.  (In MySQL 5.0, virtually all `ALTERs` are performed by copying the table over.)

Another tip when disk space is terribly tight...  (Assuming innodb_file_per_table has always been on):  `OPTIMIZE` smaller tables; Some of them may shrink a little bit, thereby giving you some extra disk space.

Another tip:

1. Determine which tables are in their own tablespaces.
2. Find out how much free space is in `ibdata1`.
3. `SET innodb_file_per_table=OFF;`
4. `ALTER TABLE t ENGINE=InnoDB;` for some of the small tables is step 1.  But stop before Data_free of ibdata1 drops too small.

That tip will free up the space for those table that could be moved without causing ibdata1 to grow.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Disk is almost full. and DB root space takes up 93% of total. So I need to shrink ibd file 33G to 19G.
and how much I need spaces for optimize? is it just copy 19G for optimize?

we delete a bunch of rows making 19G. but os capacity still takes up 33G. every day, about 100,000 rows inserting. and it increases 24m to 40m. 

I am not sure how much rows we delete before.

Comment: You will need an extra 19GB to do the `OPTIMIZE`.  (That number is approximate.)

Comment: @HyeongwooPark - And I added some tips.  For more discussion, provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS;`

Comment: Name: tableSample
/Engine: InnoDB
/Version: 10
/Rows: 54252075
/Avg_row_length: 215
/Data_length: 11683250176
/Index_length: 8881471488
/Data_free: 6291456

this one is I want to fix.

Comment: @HyeongwooPark - How much free disk space do you have?  Even if it is less than 19GB, `OPTIMIZE` may succeed.  If it fails, (or hangs, and you kill it), no harm should be done.